# Implementation on your own DTN or interplanetary communication

Tags: c

I'm asking in a theoretically way how an interplanetary communication should be implemented using the NASA DTN system. I'm asking this because I am really curious for a personal project regarding this using a client/server system but no specific documentation could be found.

Comment: I have no experience of this protocol, but it looks like they have a lot of information linked from this page: https://www.nasa.gov/content/dtn. You have seen this and don't think it gives you enough information?